# ED-XRF Detector Operation

Tags: x-rays

ED-XRF detector operates by detecting the photons that hit it's semiconductor surface and measure the energy of the fluorescent photons by measuring the current that was generated by photon. The value of the current is proportional to the energy of the photon which is defined by an atom that has generated this fluorescent photon.

What I don't understand is, how does detector knows whether it was hit by a single photon with energy of, lets say, 2 keV or by two photons with energies of 1 keV each that has arrived simultaneously and resulted in the same total current. The energy values of the photons are purely hypothetical.

I know that detectors have some maximum counts/second values, but two simultaneous photons must be a common occurrence. So my question is, how can ED-XRF detector distinguish between one photon and multiple photons hitting its surface simultaneously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having sufficient time-resolution is the key in being able to differentiate between events caused by multi-photon impacts and events caused by single-photon impacts. From the Wikipedia article on [X-ray fluorescence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_fluorescence),

> Peak length discrimination is used to eliminate events that seem to have been produced by two X-ray photons arriving almost simultaneously.

Given a detector response time $\tau$ and average rate of photon input $R$, the distribution of photon counts $k$ occurring in the time interval $\tau$ is Poisson-distributed,
$$f(k,R\tau)=\frac{e^{-R \tau } (R \tau )^k}{k!}$$
and so you can make multiphoton events negligible by designing the device to operate in a regime where they are unlikely.

In effect, you try to make $\tau$ as short as possible for your device, you make sure that the count rate $R$ does not exceed a certain threshold, and you try to filter out the few instances where multi-photon excitations seem to have happened.

Comment: Interesting. So, can I assume then the basic principle of ED XRF is the low statistical probability of multi photon events? I am going to use an off the shelf SDD spectrometer, can I say then that I can control probability if such events by varying the sample exposure time  and the primary radiation intensity?

Comment: @udushu: I suspect the answer is yes to both questions, but I would double-check with someone else if you think it could be important to your results; I don't really have a background in nuclear science.